# Good resources on properly using a sliding table saw

Tags: table-saw

​I haven't found any good resources on the different ways to take advantage of sliding table saws.

For example, what kind of sleds to build (to work with and not against the slide), what is the safest way to do different cuts compared to a regular table saw, ripping long pieces, etc...

(I do see many resources on properly using a regular table saw.)
​​

Comment: I thought the advantage of a sliding table saw was that you didn't need to use sleds to safely, accurately, and cleanly make any type of crosscut? Also, how would ripping operations be any different vs. a regular table saw. In any event, you may find it helpful to look up work people have done using the ryobi bt3000. It is a small, universal motor-powered table saw that (i believe) is the only one of its size to incorporate a sliding table. It has a devoted following of hobbyist users, and if there are jigs to use with a sliding saw, you'll find em in there.

Comment: very interesting suggestion @aaron. 
there indeed is a small bt3000 community!

Comment: see http://www.sawdustzone.org/forum/discussions/bt3x00-related-discussions (apparently the old bt3central.com migrated to this new site..)

Comment: Just a note, asking for external resources is not really in the spirit of SE, which aims to be a self-contained, canonical source (but with references to external resources as appropriate) in order to limit the amount of content that is lost due to external sources disappearing. It would also be helpful if you frame your question--for example, do you already own a sliding table saw and are you stumped on how to perform certain operations on it, or are you considering buying one and trying to understand what "gotchas" there would be in switching to one from a conventional table saw?

Comment: good point @rob; noted.

Answer (score 1):

A good sliding table can serve as a main reference point for your jigs and support for the stock. Fixing the jig/sled to the table and using the sliding action to get the stock moved across the blade. Most T-track based jigs will work fine with it.

For ripping long board you can add a shoe at the end of the table to hold the end in place as you are pushing it through. A spike in the shoe can help prevent the piece from shifting side to side.

Comment: yeah, i'm somewhat struggling with the lack of a good mitre reference for the sliding part of my saw; so I'm trying to see what kinds of things there are for this. I guess I'll just have to hack something together.

Comment: A fence on the sliding table referenced to the near end of the T-track and a stop over to the side will help with that.